# no result coming in search in alfresco community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Using Alfreco community 5.0.d and getting below error which is not letting me find ay result on search.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-4] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 00180000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00180012 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js': 00180011 Failed to execute search:  +@cm\:modified:[2017\-1\-11T00\:00\:00.000 TO 2017\-1\-18T23\:59\:59.999] +@cm\:modifier:"admin" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"bcpg:entityTplAspect" +(TYPE:"content" OR TYPE:"app:filelink" OR TYPE:"folder" )
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 00180000 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00180012 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js': 00180011 Failed to execute search:  +@cm\:modified:[2017\-1\-11T00\:00\:00.000 TO 2017\-1\-18T23\:59\:59.999] +@cm\:modifier:"admin" +(TYPE:"cm:content" OR  TYPE:"bcpg:entityV2") -TYPE:"cm:systemfolder" -TYPE:"fm:forums" -TYPE:"fm:forum" -TYPE:"fm:topic" -TYPE:"fm:post" -TYPE:"bcpg:entityListItem" -ASPECT:"bcpg:compositeVersion" -ASPECT:"bcpg:hiddenFolder" -ASPECT:"bcpg:entityTplAspect" +(TYPE:"content" OR TYPE:"app:filelink" OR TYPE:"folder" )
    at
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about what specifically you're doing to get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're executing a template rather than the actual web script. You should call it via:

```
/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/doclist/...
```

You can find the reference locally via the web scripts service index. (e.g., http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/all )

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed
Issue was related to ssl certificate being untrusted because of that solr4 and alfresco repo could not connect.

Link - http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ssl-protect-solrwebapp.html

All search and tags are working fine after this. Configure the certificate and alfresco is working properly.